# Forms of Exchange

Tags: riddle

> like an RPG character, i seek a Disciple
>
> Naturally Speaking, one will increase my Productivity.
>
> Seekers of the position might look to the Arcade
>
> and take the Rocket to the World i have Built
>
> Puzzling, aren't i? you may need a Magnifying Glass to guess my true form.

What creature am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haha, unfortunately I am already familiar with one of the topics, so the rest filled itself in.  You are...

> A dragon!

like an RPG character, i seek a Disciple

> SE Site: [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)
>  Topic: [Dragon Disciple (Pathfinder)](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_disciple)

Naturally Speaking, one will increase my Productivity.

> SE Site: [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/)
>  Topic: [Dragon NaturallySpeaking (voice-to-text software)](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm)

Seekers of the position might look to the Arcade

> SE Site: [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)
>  Topic: [Dragon Seekers (Elder Scrolls)](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Seekers)

and take the Rocket to the World i have Built

> SE Site: [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)
>  Topic: [Dragon spacecraft (SpaceX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_(spacecraft))

Puzzling, aren't i? you may need a Magnifying Glass to guess my true form.

> Could just refer to needing to use the search tool to find the common thread, but whattayaknow, there's a puzzle.
>  SE Site: [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)
>  Topic: [The Dragon or the Magnifying Glass? (lateral-thinking)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/the-dragon-or-the-magnifying-glass)

Title: "Forms of Exchange"

> Refers, obviously, to the different Stack Exchange sites that are referenced.

**BONUS**

> Accidental/inconspicuous dragon...
>
>  Site: [Stack Exchange (at large)](http://stackexchange.com/users/7639250/christopher-gray?tab=accounts)
>  Topic: [ChronoD](http://dragonsofatlantis.wikia.com/wiki/Chrono_Dragon)

**Self-imposed bonus!**

> @ChronoD: "I actually didn't use Anime just because it was difficult to find a match for."
>
>  `i'd prefer someone rather Animated with the Balls to do anything i ask.`
>  SE Site: [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/)
>  Topic: [Dragon Ball (and variants)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball)

Comment: Correct answer! Although there is something slightly different to the meaning of each phrase, if you'd care to figure it out.

Comment: @ChronoD: '-' ...erm?

Comment: Would you like a hint or would you like the answer? Because I doubt anyone else would be interested enough to search at this point.

Comment: @ChronoD: Hint, hint!  I'm just not sure how far to read into each thing or what I'm even looking for past this point.

Comment: Dragons can be found quite easily if you know where they are. But finding them by accident, that's the hard part. There are few things as pleasing as finding something you weren't looking for.

Comment: @ChronoD: ^ ^ ^ how about now?

Comment: Oh hahaha not quite. Although I would accept that if it was a badge or something.

Comment: @ChronoD On a random side note, you live really close to me!

Comment: @WesleySitu Interesting o.0 I'm currently going to CPP if you're familiar. But one last time, care for the answer or would you like to guess again?

Comment: @ChronoD Yes, that's about 10 minutes away from me haha

Comment: @ChronoD Imma call \*derp\* on this one, cuz I'm pretty dang happy with my bonus (not to mention my personal addition to the puzzle). \**stupid face\**

Comment: Very well then. If you go to the respective forms and search for the matching phrase, the first result is related to dragons. You find dragons when searching for another topic. That's why I couldn't get it with anime. No matter what I tried, I couldn't find a search result that yielded a Dragon thread as the top result. I felt that gave it a little more grounding, and it would easily reveal a pattern if you tried more than one of the forms.

Comment: Oh. Well, I touched upon it lightly with the Puzzling entry.  Meh.  Like I said, happy with the extra stuff in my answer. [mah face](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/c/c3/Horse.png/revision/latest?cb=20101015012331)

Answer (score 1):

You're...

> yourself! These are all of the Stack Exchange sites you visit.

RPG:

> Role-Playing Games

Disciple:

> Religious SE subdomains?

Naturally:

> Health?

Speaking:

> English Language & Usage

Productivity:

> Personal Productivity

Seekers

> Information **Sec**urity?

Arcade

> Arqade

Rocket

> Sci-Fi + Fantasy?

World...Built

> Worldbuilding

Puzzling

> Puzzling

Magnifying Glass

> Lifehacks?

Comment: You're close but not quite. I am, in fact, an actual creature. At least half of your assumptions are correct, but the other half... aren't quite being used correctly. The ones without ?'s are correct.

Comment: @ChronoD: What about now?

Comment: Another valiant attempt, but you're father down the incorrect path. The ones you're missing aren't Stack Exchanges.

Comment: @ChronoD Are you Nina Tucker?

Comment: @WesleySitu No I'm not, but I'm curious how you got to that. Is it because I didn't mention Anime?

Comment: That's one of the Stack Exchange communities you were part of, and if you combine all these strange things together.... you get something like her. haha

Comment: @WesleySitu I figured it was something along those lines xD I actually didn't use Anime just because it was difficult to find a match for.

Comment: @WesleySitu: Too soon! T-T